# How to redirect all unauthorized requests to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f? mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to redirect all unauthorized requests to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f?`

```
.NET framework version 4.5
```

using ASP.NET Identity so i don't have the likes of

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: This is a default behavior if you use ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: @Alex Art Hi, i don't think it is default. created a new project with auth. Hitting ctrl F5 just sent me to the home index page while i needed to go to the account/login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are using the last MVC 5 default template wich is configured to use Owin, you can achieve want you want by configuring it in the `Startup` class  :

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MvcApplication.Startup))]
namespace MvcApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
                // Configure the rest as you need
            });
        }
    }
}
```

For further informations, you can read this great [article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application) written by an MVP.